# How to iterate three different collections together

Tags: java, data-structures

I have three collections,
the first two are reference data and the third is the actual dataset.
I am trying to check that data for an account exists for the reference date collection.
If it is not there,
I need add dummy data for that account for the day.
What would be best iteration logic to follow here for optimal performance.
I cannot change the List dataset to hashmap it is given as List.

Here is some code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class FindAccountExistForDay {

    public String userStart;
    public String accountId;
    public String genre;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Set<String> accounts= new HashSet<String>();
        accounts.add("1");
        accounts.add("2");
        accounts.add("3");
        accounts.add("4");
        accounts.add("5");
        accounts.add("6");

        Set<String> dates= new HashSet<String>();
        dates.add("05032018");
        dates.add("05042018");
        dates.add("05052018");
        dates.add("05062018");
        dates.add("05072018");
        dates.add("05082018");
        dates.add("05092018");



        List<String[]> dataList= new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] strings = {"05032018", "1", "John"};
        String[] strings2 = {"05042018", "1", "John"};
        String[] strings3 = {"05062018", "3", "David"};
        String[] strings4 = {"05072018", "4", "Gilbert"};
        String[] strings5 = {"05082018", "5", "Mark"};
        String[] strings6 = {"05092018", "6", "Neil"};
        String[] strings7 = {"05032018", "2", "Dan"};

        dataList.add( strings);
        dataList.add( strings2);
        dataList.add( strings3);
        dataList.add( strings4);
        dataList.add( strings5);
        dataList.add( strings6);
        dataList.add( strings7);

    for (String date: dates){
        Set<Object> groupSet= new HashSet<Object>();
            for (String acct: accounts){
                while(dataList.iterator().hasNext()){
                    //do the logic here?
              } 
            }
            System.out.println("date:"+ date +":"+ groupSet);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Iterate through dataList and check if e.g strings2 value contains value that are inside other list if I understand question correctly. Use contains() method

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you looking for?

```
for (final String[] strs : dataList) {
   final String date = strs[0];

   if (!dates.contains(date)) {

   }
}
```

**Using Stream API (Java 8)**

```
dataList.stream().filter(strs -> !dates.contains(strs[0]))
```

**or more expressive**

```
dataList.stream().map(strs -> strings[0]).filter(date -> !dates.contains(date))
```

Comment: I primary purpose is to fill dummy data for missing days, I need to check both date and account in parallel

Answer (score 1):

Use below logic

```
 for (String date: dates){
    Set<Object> groupSet= new HashSet<Object>();
        for (String acct: accounts){
            Iterator<String[]> iterator=dataList.iterator();
            boolean b=false;
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                //do the logic here?
                List checkList=Arrays.asList(iterator.next());
                b=checkList.contains(date)&&checkList.contains(acct);
                if(b)break;
          }
          if(!b){
              //add dummy data here
              System.out.println(date + "  "+acct);
          }

        }
        System.out.println("date:"+ date +":"+ groupSet);
    }
}
```